# Use init{} in viewmodel failed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, navigation

I am using a ViewModel and the `init{}` block as below:

```
class AccountViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userProfileUseCases: UserProfileUseCases,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uIState = MutableStateFlow<UIState>(UIState.Empty)
    val uIState: StateFlow<UIState> = _uIState

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _uIState.value = UIState.Loading
            getUserProfile()
        }
    }

suspend fun getUserProfile() = userProfileUseCases.getUserProfile().collect { result ->
        when (result) {
            is Success -> {
                result.data?.let { userProfile ->
                    _uIState.value = UIState.UpdateUserProfile(userProfile)
                }
            }
```

and then the Fragment catch the `UpdateUserProfile` and update the UI. In order to navigate within the app, I am using a navigation component. The fragment display the profile of the user but to edit/modify it, I am using another fragment and navigate to it using `findNavController().safeNavigation`. The click open the new fragment and do what I want.

In this new fragment, I can go back to the caller, aka back to the user profile fragment. I am using the code `navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)`.

it's working but the profile is empty like the `init {}` is not called anymore on the back action.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: please share the code of fragment from where it is injected.

Answer (score 3):

An `init` block or Initializer blocks is executed immediately after the primary constructor and only gets called once in the lifecycle of an Object; it's basically the constructor's first line.

When you press back from `UpdateUserProfile`, it pops the back stack and goes to your `ProfileFragment`, but the ViewModel instance remains the same, so `init` will not get called.

You can just pass the data back to `ProfileFragment` to update its UI.
There are several ways to do this:

- you can use [FragmentResultAPI](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result), or
- you can use [`SavedStateHandle`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result)

Comment: Well, no, you shouldn't be trying to pass back an updated profile. The ViewModel should have been using a `Flow` or other observable pattern in the first place that would automatically get the updated state, rather than a one time operation.

Comment: my bad i did not not mean to say pass the Object itself .. just a flag that data profile has been updated and reload it ..  Using Flow and any other observable also make sense. i m not sure about the implementation of this .. Since VM is not shared so we need to make the call in Repo ..this seems possible only if Repo expose a Single Flow object for each `getProfile` call .